# Key based Decoder program not working

Tags: python, decode

I'm trying to make a program that decodes encoded messages. I've created 2 separate lists for upper and lowercase letter. But every time I input a message with spaces the first letter of the message keep output after every word.

```
    n1=1
    while n1!=0:
        n=input("\nEnter code")
        n1=int(n[0])
        newcode=n[1:]
        list1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'
           ,'m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        list2=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R'
           ,'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
        list3=[]
        list4=[]
        for x in newcode:
            if i in list1:
                n=list1.index(i)
                n2=n-n1
                y=list1[n2]
                print(y, end="")
            else:
                list3.append(i)
                for x in list3:
                    if i in list2:
                        n=list2.index(i)
                        n2=n-n1
                        y=list2[n2]
                        print(y, end="")
                    else:
                        print(i, end="")

                    if n1==0:
                        '/n'
                        break
```

> Sample input: 3Wkh fdu lu eoxh
>
> > Sample ouput:
> >     TheT carT  isT   blue
> >
> > > Sample input:
> > >       9Rc'b j carlthxwn
> > >
> > > > Sample output:
> > > >         ItI'sI' aI'  trickyI'   one

Comment: Start by fixing the indentation of your program so that it appears in the question the same way it appears in your file.  I should be able to copy / paste it and have it run.

Comment: As a side note, having `for x in…` with another `for x in…` directly beneath it probably isn't your problem, but it definitely is confusing. Give the four variables different names. If you're trying to signal that you don't want to use the outer one, do that by giving it the name `_`, not by giving it a name that will be shadowed later.

Comment: More generally, names like `n`, `n1`, `x` have no intrinsic meaning, so they make it hard to understand what your program is doing. If you want us to guess how your program is supposed to be working so we can tell you how to fix it, meaningful names will make that a lot easier to do.

Comment: What I mean by n and x is for the program to check every single character of a given string, while decoding it.

Comment: The code uses the variable `i` which is not assigned anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could run your program without problem and reproduce. The problem is not only that the first letter is repeated after each word. In fact, all works fine for lower case letters, but upper case letter spaces and other accumulates and are consistently repeated.

All that comes from this line : `list3.append(x)` that accumulates in `list3` all not lower case letters.

I have not spent enough time to fully analyse you script, but here is a quick and dirty fix:

- replace line 10 : `list3 = []` with `list3 = ['']` (that is make list3 a list with 1 element)
- replace line 19 : `list3.append(x)` with `list3[0] = x` (that is keep list3 of size 1, and put new element in lieue of previous one)

I did it and with you example inputs, I get :

```
The car ir blue
It's a trickyone
```

(note that spaces are non longer duplicated)